# Return reference to a primitive parameter

Tags: c++, templates, reference

I have a function like this

```
template<typename T>
const T& get(std::string key, T defaultValue)
{
    try {
        return getFromMap<T>(key);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Which retrieves a typed value from a mixed type map, returning the defaultValue if the key is not found. There are primitive and object types as values in the map (thus we must return a reference to the value). We only need to worry about primitive defaultValues; using it with our object values is unsupported. This function works fine on linux, however when running on windows my returned defaultValues are garbage. For example,

get("missing", true) returns false (ie 0)

get("missing", 3.14) returns 0

get("missing", "myDefault") returns a junk address

and so on. I guess the problem is something like that the defaultValue is getting copied into a new variable inside the function, and then a reference to a temporary is returned. How can I fix my function to do the right thing on windows?

Comment: You can just return by value. The copy elision will make that optimal.

Comment: If you only have "primitive values" (I assume like `int` or `double`) then always pass and return by value. No need for references at all.

Comment: Rule of thumb: Never return a reference to a non static local variable or a non reference function parameter.

Comment: Remove '&' before get

Answer (score 2):

First off, your function is broken regardless of operating system. The reason is that it has Undefined Behaviour when the exceptional case happens: you're returning a reference to a function-local object (the parameter `defaultValue`). Such a reference becomes dangling as soon as the function exits, and accessing an object through a dangling reference is UB. That it happens to work on Linux is just bad luck, and it could easily break by changing compiler version, compilation switches, other parts of source code, or pretty much anything else.

I'm afraid the problem you're facing doesn't have a solution which is both quick & clean.

I think you might be best off by providing two overloads of `get`, one for primitive types which will return by value, and one for non-primitive types which will return by `const T &` (and not support default values, which you mentioned is OK for you). You could go about it like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental<T>::value>>
T get(const std::string &key, T defaultValue)
{
    try {
        return getFromMap<T>(key);
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }
}

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental<T>::value>>
const T& get(const std::string &key)
{
    return getFromMap<T>(key);
}
```

Notice that I changed `get` to take its `key` parameter by `const&`. If you're worried about performance, you should not copy `key` just to read from it.